# Java Collection<Generic Type> Sorting without Collections

Tags: java, collections, comparator

I'm really stuck on an assignment for school. We are learning about Generic Types, and maybe this is me not just understanding them fully, but as part of one of the first methods we have to implement:

We have:

```
public static <T> T min(Collection<T> c, Comparator<T> comp) {
        return null
}
```

And the requirements:

Selects the minimum value from the `Collection c`, as defined by the
supplied `Comparator comp`. This method throws an `IllegalArgumentException`
if either c or comp is null, and it throws a `NoSuchElementException` if c
is empty. The Collection c is not changed by this method.

So I've gotten to here:

```
public static <T> T min(Collection<T> c, Comparator<T> comp)
            throws IllegalArgumentException, NoSuchElementException {
        if (c != null && comp != null) {
            if (!c.isEmpty()) {

            } else {
                throw new NoSuchElementException();
            }
        } else {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        }
    }
```

We have to sort using a comparator, but CANNOT use the Collections class. I really just need some direction to start, I'm not asking you to do the assignment for me!

Comment: Arrays.sort()? http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#sort(T[],%20java.util.Comparator)

Comment: @robert Working around the use of `Collections.sort` by using the `Arrays` version is probably not what the instructor had in mind

Comment: So thinking abstractly, if you had a list fill of something... I dunno, toys(?) how would you go about finding the least heavy of the toys?

Comment: Yeah definitely can't use Arrays.sort(), there's no guarantee it's not an arraylist or list, etc.

Comment: Oh right, to implement yourself, just iterate over the collection. Invoke the `compareTo` and keep the instance that evaluates less than. At the end of iteration return the instance that remains.

Comment: I'd compare all the toys to one another individually, so use an iterator to go through each one (iterator.next()), but my problem is, what to I type each object? How do I compare a generic object to another generic thing?

Comment: use `Collection<T extends Comparable>` in the method signature.

Comment: @robert `T extends Comparable` is not needed. Do not confuse `Comparable` with `Comparator`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It should be easy. Comparator is used to compare two elements not for sorting. Sorting is not necessary here. You don't want to change the collection, just find the minimum value. You can just take first one and iterate over the collection comparing choosen element to others, switching choosen element to another when it's bigger. This is the way to find the minimum.

Comment: Thank you very much for following the 'just a hint' directions haha

Comment: I think it's a good thinking. When you get the hint you'll learn more.

Comment: So essentially this is doing the same thing as a regular non, generic type min function, but with generic typing? Is there a way to give a generic 'T' variable null value? Eclipse complains that null or false, or 0 is not a <T> variable.

Comment: You can cast null to any type like `return (T) null;`

Comment: @SCHULTZ Probably is just an Eclipse Warning that you may disable. NetBeans seems to ignore it when doing `T val = null;`

Comment: An alternative to iteration is to use [a fold with Java8](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#reduce-T-java.util.function.BinaryOperator-). Most courses cover folds in their functional language part, so the instructor probably won't object

Comment: Thank you all for the help!

Answer (score 2):

Pseudocode of what you need to add to your example:

- Save the first element in a variable call "minimum". As it is declared generic the type of the object is T.
- Iterate the collection (Clue: every collection has an iterator)
- Compare each element with the "minimum" found. If lower than assign it to the minimum.
- Return the variable minimum.

I won't put the code as it is homework and you need to familiarize with the syntax.